# Elastic Search error in complex bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to make an elasticsearch query where, I need to search for a time frame in the elasticsearch table. I have records which has startime and endtime. And from UI I am giving a starttime and endtime which is time windows for which I need to search files for. Assuming the time window of starttime and endtime in the records is smaller than the time window entered by user, I have created the following query:

```
    {
    "_source":["filename","starttime","endtime"],
    "sort":[{
        "starttime":{"order":"asc"}
    }],
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":{
                "bool":{
                    "must":[
                        "range":{
                            "starttime":{
                                "lte":1489602610000
                            }
                        },
                        "range":{
                            "endtime":{
                                "gte":1489602610000,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "should":{
                "bool":{
                    "must":[
                        "range":{
                            "starttime":{
                                "gte":1489602610000
                            }
                        },
                        "range":{
                            "endtime":{
                                "lte":1489689000000
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "should":{
                "bool":{
                    "must":[
                        "range":{
                            "starttime":{
                                "lte":1489689000000
                            }
                        },
                        "range":{
                            "endtime":{
                                "gte":1489689000000
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            }
        }
}
```

I am getting error

> "Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate
>   Array entries\n at [Source:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@29263f09; line:
>   11, column: 33]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your query:

- one dangling comma
- more than one `bool/should` clauses
- `range` queries not properly wrapped inside curly braces

You can find the correct query below:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "filename",
    "starttime",
    "endtime"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "starttime": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "starttime": {
                    "lte": 1489602610000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endtime": {
                    "gte": 1489602610000
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "starttime": {
                    "gte": 1489602610000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endtime": {
                    "lte": 1489689000000
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "starttime": {
                    "lte": 1489689000000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endtime": {
                    "gte": 1489689000000
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```